# AngularJS route parameter random number of slashes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I am creating an AngularJS application which will get content from The Guardian API. I am using routing, so when it's at "articles/:articleId", I can get the articleId parameter. In this case, "articles/123" works fine, it returns 123, but The Guardian API id's are:

```
technology/competition/2013/nov/01/observer-tech-monthly-student-competition
```

So, it doesn't recognise news/:articleId as the route anymore, instead, it skips that controller and goes back to the normal (.otherwise()) controller. Is there any way that I could get the whole things after /news, in this case, the whole parameter to be returned:

```
technology/competition/2013/nov/01/observer-tech-monthly-student-competition
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Angular 1.1.5* introduced `*path`

For example, routes like

```
 `/color/:color/largecode/*largecode/edit`
```

will match

```
`/color/brown/largecode/code/with/slashs/edit`
```

and extract:

```
color: brown
largecode: code/with/slashs
```

In *Angular 1.3*, the **syntax changed** to `:path*`

In conclusion, if you are using *Angular 1.3*, I imagine that you want your route to look something like this:

```
articles/:articleId*
```